# how can I create extensions and domains in template1

Tags: postgresql

Hi How can I CREATE EXTENTIONS and DOMAINS in template1 so that when I create new DB's afterwards these will be included. Using SQL commands, not linux! ie. in Navicat using a query?  Thx

Answer (score 1):

You connect to database `template1` as superuser and run a `CREATE EXTENSION` or `CREATE DOMAIN` command.

It's as simple as that.